# How to include page specific javascript in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Doing a google search gives depreciated answers for older versions of rails or says to use turbolinks. I like the idea of the coffeescript files but don't want to write everything in coffeescript is there a way to have a item.coffee and item.js file so it reads both. I saw this in a rails cast but that video was pretty old and that approach doesn't seem to work now.

If the only way is to use turbolinks to add page specific js to a page how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the answers to your questions; this might be verbose...

---

> is there a way to have a item.coffee and item.js file so it reads both

`Coffeescript` is a [pre-processor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark).

In as much the same way as `SCSS`/`SASS`, it runs through "coffeescript" code and translates into standardized JS. In short, coffeescript is not a "language" in itself, it's just [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) for standard JS.

This means that if you're using a `coffeescript` extension, you *can* still use standard JS with it:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/item.js.coffee
alert("hello"); #-> Js
alert "hello"   #-> Cs
```

... same functionality.

--

> If the only way is to use turbolinks to add page specific js to a page how is that done

It's not the "only" way. [It's no way at all](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#turbolinks):

> Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it [Turbolinks] keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body (or parts of) and the title in the head

Turbolinks replaces the `<body>` of your page *if* the assets remain the same (it speeds up page load by removing the need to re-initialize the assets each time).

Of course, this is null & void when dealing with different assets.

If you have a different set of assets (different layout etc), `Turbolinks` will reload as appropriate:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, (:transactions if controller_name == "transactions") %>
```

In this case, Turbolinks refreshes the entire page, which will update your assets through the refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: If I add js coding to a coffee script file it usually breaks. Do i need to declare that it is js coding or something?

Comment: What's the filename? `.js.coffee` should get it working. It's like having `erb` in your JS - can only be recognized if you use `.js.erb`